# Checkbox implementation in Angular2 using Material

Tags: css, checkbox, input, angular, angular2-material

I'm trying to implement a checkbox in Angular2 using Material. I've referred to https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular2-material/checkbox which contains everything about using checkboxes in Angular2 using Material. But, its too complex and time consuming to study and use that.

If any of you have implemented it, please help me.[I want the checkbox to look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0avW.png)

Answer (score 1):

For simple cases I use http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Getting started http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

For checked checkbox I'm using http://fontawesome.io/icon/check-square/ and http://fontawesome.io/icon/check-square-o/
For unchecked http://fontawesome.io/icon/square-o/